# Counts and character lengths on specific columns in a large dataframe

Tags: r

would really like some help!

I've got a dataframe that's 400000 obs by 12 variables(columns) with alphanumeric information. To simplify, lets say these are two of columns in the dataframe. 
Col1 = a, b, a, c, e, a, b, c
Col2 = AAAA, BB, CCCCCC, AAA, BB, CC, AAAA, BB, CCCCCC

1. Want an output that creates a mean of the length of all values (ex. "AAAA" = length is 4) in column 2 for each value of column 1. Ex:  for value "a" in col1 the output would be 4 (AAAA=4; CCCCCC=6; CC=2; mean = 4).
2. Want an output that gives me the number of times a particular value in col 2 exists in the whole data set - but want it subsetted by values of column 1.

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. `str_count(Col2, ".")` counts how many letters exist. In this way, I measured length of the string. Then, I grouped the data by `Col1` and calculated mean. That is for the first part. As for the 2nd part, I used `count()` in the `dplyr` package. I hope this is what you meant.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

# For the first part
mutate(mydf, num = str_count(Col2, ".")) %>%
group_by(Col1) %>%
summarise(num.Ave = sum(num) / n())

#  Col1 num.Ave
#1    a     4.0
#2    b     3.0
#3    c     2.5
#4    e     2.0

# For the 2nd part

count(mydf, Col1, Col2)

#  Col1   Col2 n
#1    a   AAAA 1
#2    a     CC 1
#3    a CCCCCC 1
#4    b   AAAA 1
#5    b     BB 1
#6    c    AAA 1
#7    c     BB 1
#8    e     BB 1
```

DATA

```
mydf <- structure(list(Col1 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "e", "a", "b", "c"
), Col2 = c("AAAA", "BB", "CCCCCC", "AAA", "BB", "CC", "AAAA", 
"BB")), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

# mydf
#  Col1   Col2
#1    a   AAAA
#2    b     BB
#3    a CCCCCC
#4    c    AAA
#5    e     BB
#6    a     CC
#7    b   AAAA
#8    c     BB
```

Comment: @Nina Thanks for your comment. After posting my suggestion, I thought using `nchar` will do. `mutate(mydf, num = nchar(Col2))`. As for your stats question, I am not sure how your actual data looks like. So I am afraid I cannot answer.

Comment: Thank you! The first solution worked well! Wondering if you know how I can add some statistical data with that mean - so get a t-test pvalue, standard deviation etc for each mean.

The second solution worked well as well! I'm trying to sort on the df that the count code generates and i keep getting weird things. Ex. i did
> count=count(set, Col1, Col2)
>sortedcount = count[order("Col2")]
That gave me only Col2 and arranged in an assecending order. 

This gave me only one row of the whole df. 
sortedcount = count[order("Col2"),]

I know it should be so simple but just can't figure out how to!

Comment: @Nina I am sorry for this late reply. I did not have time to commit myself to SO for a few days. As for the second part, you can use `arrange()` from `dplyr`. Could you try the following? `count(mydf, Col1, Col2) %>% ungroup %>% arrange(Col2)`